# What could be the reason that logistic regression outperforms recurrent neural network in a binary classification task?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, logistic-regression, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataset of 20000 samples, 24 time steps, and 40 features. by applying logistic regression on (20000,24*40) the performance is better than applying recurrent neural networks on (20000,24,40). what could be the possible reasons?
could something go wrong during the data preprocessing?

Comment: Maybe the number of samples is not enough for the problem you are trying to train. Deep learning methods are powerful when you have many samples and they are able to learn many details about your problem (complex decision boundaries)

Comment: How are you measuring performance?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity I've been using Sensitivity, specificity, roc-curve, area under precision-recall and Matthew correlation coefficient.

Comment: How are you measuring them - on a holdout set? With crossvalidation?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity I am measuring them using both methods (holdout set, cross-validation)